# How to set multiple logos to windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps, manifest

recently I've seen an win 8 store app, that had 2 logos that they were changing after time in metro of course.

I want implement this to my application but i cant figure out how to add more logos and say to system that these two will change.

I've tried to add more logos to manifest, but it didnt worked.

Or just the developers of app made the logo as a GIF?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this behaviour with live tiles using [NotificationExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969156.aspx) to [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465439.aspx) a tile update with an image, and [scheduled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761473.aspx) or [periodic](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-example-of-using-periodic-notifications-for-live-tiles/) notifications

Answer (score 0):

When you say logo, I presume you mean the tile on the Start Screen?  You can effect a change there through a variety of mechanisms including local, scheduled, periodic, and push notifications.  If you simply have a static number of images you want to cycle through and bundle with your application then use either [local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868253%28v=win.10%29.aspx) or [scheduled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868223%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

I wrote a [pretty extensive blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/02/windows-8-notifications-programmatic-concepts.aspx) on all of these options a while ago, and there's [great information on these as well at the dev center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779725.aspx).  The first segment of the Week 3 coverage of the [App Builder program](http://aka.ms/8in30SO) also puts this information into the overall context of building your app.